# How can I easily find other players in Mincraft PE multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

We are playing multiplayer on a local wifi on Minecraft PE. Since it is an unlimited world size, when a new player joins the world we cannot find each other. Is there an easy way to find each other or teleport to where player is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is when remember where the spawn point is. This can be done by maybe making a tower or something that help designate the area. Unfortunately to find spawn you must make a NEW friend stay were he is until you find him to know precisely where spawn is. Hope that helped :D

Answer (score 5):

Type /tp (playername) or if you are in a server that you do not own, or you are not op, type /tpa (playername) this will send a notification to the other player and they have a choice to accept the tpa (/tpaccept) or decline (/tpdecline)

Comment: This question is seven months old and already has an accepted answer, so there is no need to add additional answers. Also, the question is about Minecraft PE, so there is no commands in the vanilla game.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. The original answer gives you one solution that is barely a solution.  This answer can (potentially) give you a much more powerful, and direct solution.  It would have been more accurate and useful if the answerer specified that a specific mod or hack is needed, but even referencing that this possibility exists was enough for me to go hunting for it and ultimately gave me a much better minecraft experience.  I would personally change this answer to the accepted one or at the very least upvote this answer (and regardless, not downvote it to negative point land!)

Comment: /tp also works on Windows 10 edition.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the following tools, which should be fine if you're in Creative mode:

- The compass
- The ability to fly
- A bit of patience

If Steve has built something far from the spawn point and Alex wants to find it, Steve will have to do most of the work here. Let's assume that Steve is standing by his work of art, whilst Alex is lost somewhere (having wandered for hours without finding anything).

The key thing to realise is that the compass doesn't point in a fixed direction along an axis of the world, but rather it always points to the initial spawn point.

Steve should start by building a very tall tower somewhere near his base. The easiest way is to start flying near the ground, look straight down, and keep tapping build whilst flying straight up. In a few seconds you'll have a very conspicuous totem pole reaching to the sky.

Now Steve needs to float in the air near the totem pole, facing due South (that is, with the compass needle pointing straight backwards). Steve should then fly backwards (keeping an eye on the compass to ensure he keeps going in the same direction) until the totem pole just starts to fade from view. At that point, he should drop to the ground right where he is and build another sky-high totem pole.

Then, just repeat: fly near the pole, face due South, fly backwards until it starts to fade, build another pole.

Of course, since you are facing South and flying backwards, you're flying due North (i.e. straight towards the spawn point).

Meanwhile, Alex need only follow her compass due North until she reaches the spawn point. Once she arrives, she can give Steve a big hug before they make like Hansel and Gretel and hand-in-hand follow the trail of poles back home.

I used this method (after wasting two hours searching in vain) to find a building that was a 90-second flight away from the spawn point. It took only about 10 minutes. Good luck!

Comment: You could probably **Save Time** by building a sky-high totem every other totem, while building half-sized ones in between.. Once you know which direction you're going, all you need to do is make sure you can see a large one then a small one over and over.

Comment: Rather than building a tower at the spawn point, can't you just both use your compass to walk back to the spawn point (where the compass flips around from "north" to "south")? Then you'd both be in the same spot. Maybe the tower helps, but once you're both at the spawn area it's small enough that you wouldn't need anything else.

Comment: Yes, if you just want to find each other. In my case, the other player had built something impressive that they wanted me to see, but it was far from the spawn point. Fair point though.