# How can I find another player in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend's built something impressive and I want to see it. However, they built it a long way from the spawn point and they've forgotten how to get to it from there. They're afraid that if they leave it, they'll lose it too.

How can I find my way to them?

[I am aware this is a duplicate of [How can I easily find other players in Mincraft PE multiplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178165), but that question's locked so I can't add my solution. Apologies.]

Comment: Uh. The question isn't locked, it's *protected*. This means that users with reputation below 10 cannot answer it. You have 116, you can post your solution without any trouble.

Comment: Asking the same question because the original is protected is not allowed.  You need to earn 10 rep here, in order to answer it.  I'd recommend making a few edits to gather that.  Asking it again is not kosher.

Comment: @Texenox He has the rep *from* this question.  You need ten earned rep on the site in question in order to answer protected questions, and the association bonus does not count.

Comment: @Frank So that's why I haven't been able to answer protected questions on CodeGolf.SE... Okay, I understand now.

Comment: Yay! I have earned enough rep by doing the wrong thing to be able to do the right thing. I've pasted my answer to the other question. SE is a bit of a nonsense sometimes... ;)

Comment: Huh. Not enough rep to delete my duplicate question though. Ho hum...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the following tools, which should be fine if you're in Creative mode:

- The compass
- The ability to fly
- A bit of patience

If Steve has built something far from the spawn point and Alex wants to find it, Steve will have to do most of the work here. Let's assume that Steve is standing by his work of art, whilst Alex is lost somewhere (having wandered for hours without finding anything).

The key thing to realise is that the compass doesn't point in a fixed direction along an axis of the world, but rather it always points to the initial spawn point.

Steve should start by building a very tall tower somewhere near his base. The easiest way is to start flying near the ground, look straight down, and keep tapping build whilst flying straight up. In a few seconds you'll have a very conspicuous totem pole reaching to the sky.

Now Steve needs to float in the air near the totem pole, facing due South (that is, with the compass needle pointing straight backwards). Steve should then fly backwards (keeping an eye on the compass to ensure he keeps going in the same direction) until the totem pole just starts to fade from view. At that point, he should drop to the ground right where he is and build another sky-high totem pole.

Then, just repeat: fly near the pole, face due South, fly backwards until it starts to fade, build another pole.

Of course, since you are facing South and flying backwards, you're flying due North (i.e. straight towards the spawn point).

Meanwhile, Alex need only follow her compass due North until she reaches the spawn point. Once she arrives, she can give Steve a big hug before they make like Hansel and Gretel and hand-in-hand follow the trail of poles back home.

I used this method (after wasting two hours searching in vain) to find a building that was a 90-second flight away from the spawn point. It took only about 10 minutes. Good luck!